# Android 10 APK restart after update programmatically

Tags: android, installation, broadcastreceiver, apk, packageinstaller

When my app is updating itself through a downloaded APK and the PackageInstaller, it won't restart even though I implemented a BroadcastReceiver that is in fact called. The app just closes and stays closed.

My Broadcast Receiver:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;


public class LauncherReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.e("LauncherReceiver", "Received");
        Log.e("LauncherReceiver", context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName()).toString());

        Intent startIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
        startIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(startIntent);

        Log.e("LauncherReceiver", "Intent started");
    }
}
```

I get all those three messages but the App won't restart. The package manager returns the right launch activity. No error, no restart.

Can anyone please help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must call `onNewIntent()` in the activity supposed to start after updating, and declare the receiver in the Manifest. Did you achieve it?